# R - boxplot with multiple factor labels

Tags: r, label, boxplot

I'm working on trying to make a boxplot in R-cran that is categorized by two different factors on the x-axis. My problem lies in creating labels for one factor with +20 levels that spans the entire graph appropriately while using a legend to label the second factor which has only 2 to 3 levels.

Here is a test script that roughly mimics my actual dataset:

```
d<-data.frame(x=rnorm(1500),f1=rep(seq(1:20),75),f2=rep(letters[1:3],500))
# first factor has 20+ levels
d$f1<-factor(d$f1)
# second factor a,b,c
d$f2<-factor(d$f2)

boxplot(x~f2*f1,data=d,col=c("red","blue","green"),frame.plot=TRUE,axes=FALSE)

# y axis is numeric and works fine
yts=pretty(d$x,n=5)
axis(2,yts)

# I know this doesn't work; what I'd like is to spread the factors out 
# so the each group of three(a,b,c) is labeled correctly
axis(1,at=seq(1:20))

# Use the legend to handle the f2 factor labels
legend(1, max(d$x), c("a", "b","c"),fill = c("red", "blue","green"))
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

FWIW, a `ggplot2` solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = f1, y = x)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = f2), width = 0.8) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: I never realised you could theme `ggplot` plots! I was always turned off using them due to the ugly grey background. Thanks for showing me that.

Comment: @thelatemail, themeing allow almost any element in the plot to be adjusted/modified.

Comment: @thelatemail - see [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Themes) for an overview of the themes.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a label at the middle of each group of 3 boxes, try something like this:

```
axis(1,at=seq(2,60,3),labels=1:20,cex.axis=0.7)
```

[image]

To generalise, this would be:

```
groups <- 20
numbox <- 3
total <- groups * numbox
xpoints <- seq(median(1:numbox),total,numbox)
```

Comment: @Kerry - No worries! In that case, don't forget to give us both an upvote (up arrow) and choose an answer (the tick symbol below the arrows)