# Displaying multiple boxplots per group in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I have data of the form:

```
Day A   B
1   1   4
1   2   5
1   3   6
2   2   2
2   3   4
2   5   6
3   6   7
3   4   6
```

And I would like to display this on a single chart, with `Day` along the x-axis, and with each x-position having a boxplot for each of `A` and `B` (colour coded).

Comment: I'm also interested in changing the statistic used for the boxplot values, but that's perhaps a separate question.

Comment: Just so you know, many within the r tag subcommunity here will see this sort of question as fairly rude: basically a work-order, like placing an order at a restaurant. So it may attract down votes, and many will simply ignore it. On the other hand, I'm sure folks would be happy to help with a _specific_ attempt on your part that didn't work, if you share it.

Comment: This might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441214/r-boxplot-with-multiple-factor-labels

Comment: @joran Whilst I sort of understand where you're coming from I might offer that I have searched for a solution and didn't come up with anything. I generally do my stats in SPSS and end up searching for R examples or tutorials when I need to do something I can't get SPSS to do for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a (slight) modification of an example form the `?boxplot` help page. The examples show off many common uses of the functions.

```
tg <- data.frame(
   dose=ToothGrowth$dose[1:30], 
   A=ToothGrowth$len[1:30], 
   B=ToothGrowth$len[31:60]
)
head(tg)
#   dose    A    B
# 1  0.5  4.2 15.2
# 2  0.5 11.5 21.5
# 3  0.5  7.3 17.6
# 4  0.5  5.8  9.7
# 5  0.5  6.4 14.5
# 6  0.5 10.0 10.0

boxplot(A ~ dose, data = tg,
        boxwex = 0.25, at = 1:3 - 0.2,
        col = "yellow",
        main = "Guinea Pigs' Tooth Growth",
        xlab = "Vitamin C dose mg",
        ylab = "tooth length",
        xlim = c(0.5, 3.5), ylim = c(0, 35), yaxs = "i")
boxplot(B ~ dose, data = tg, add = TRUE,
        boxwex = 0.25, at = 1:3 + 0.2,
        col = "orange")
legend(2, 9, c("A", "B"),
       fill = c("yellow", "orange"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, brilliant. I'm sorry for my lack of due diligence in RTFM!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
ddf = structure(list(Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), A = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L), B = c(4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 
6L)), .Names = c("Day", "A", "B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

mm = melt(ddf, id='Day')
ggplot(mm)+geom_boxplot(aes(x=factor(Day), y=value, fill=variable))
```

[image]